# How can I return a load balanced url with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, dns

Working on a n tiered environment for a portal. To troubleshoot problems we usually need to know what web tier the user is on.

Currently we have a way of doing so...the next iteration has limited us to fewer possibilities - so the question becomes:

**The domain/tier address is xyz-01.com but going through a load balancer it comes back simply as xyz.com.**

**Is there a way to return xyz-01.com with javascript?**

Comment: can you tack on a custom HTTP header to indicate the "real" server ?

Comment: we have no control over that unfortunately